# Powershell Microsoft Teams Error, Code NotFound in spite of seemingly making no changes

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have a very simple Powershell script that I am using so that upon creating a new Microsoft Team, Channels and Users are created, and then Users are assigned to channels.  It's a very simple script, and was working just fine for months:

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
$NewTeamName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Name of new Team'
$NewTeam = New-Team -DisplayName $NewTeamName
$GroupId = $NewTeam.GroupId
Import-csv createTeamChannels.csv | foreach{New-TeamChannel -GroupId $GroupId -DisplayName $_.cname -MembershipType $_.ctype}
Import-csv createTeamUsers.csv | foreach{Add-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupId -User $_.cuser -Role $_.crole}
Import-csv addChannelUsers.csv | foreach{Add-TeamChannelUser -GroupId $GroupId -DisplayName $_.cdisplayname -User $_.cuser}
Import-csv addChannelUsers.csv | foreach{Add-TeamChannelUser -GroupId $GroupId -DisplayName $_.cdisplayname -User $_.cuser -Role $_.crole}
```

Seemingly out of nowhere, I am receiving a Code NotFound error.  The

```
New-Team: C:\Windows\System32\FullScript3.ps1:3
Line |
   3 |  $NewTeam = New-Team -DisplayName $NewTeamName
     |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Error occurred while executing
Code: NotFound
Message: Failed to execute MS Graph backend request
     | GetGroupInternalApiRequest. The server failed to respond correctly. Response Code: NotFound, Reason:
     | Reason: Not Found, Correlation headers: request-id: 3bf1b17e-5c2e-4898-85b9-2fbe82083871
     | client-request-id: 3bf1b17e-5c2e-4898-85b9-2fbe82083871 x-ms-ags-diagnostic:
     | {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"Central
     | US","Slice":"E","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"DS3PEPF00001703"}} Date: Thu, 22 Apr 2021
     | 16:56:51 GMT
InnerError:
  RequestId: 20d82423-9ba5-4f56-9f3a-b7ed1a4c0720
  DateTimeStamp:
     | 2021-04-22T16:56:52
HttpStatusCode: NotFound
```

Has anyone run into this kind of thing before?  I am flummoxed as to what I could have changed to cause these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is This error occurred for only once or multiple times?
Could you please check the PowerShell module version? if update is available please update powershell teams module.

Update-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -RequiredVersion 2.0

Comment: Update: Microsoft has released a preview version (2.1.0) of the Teams PowerShell module which works properly with modern authentication. It’s likely that this version will be pushed through to general availability quite quickly.
Please go through this link for more information. https://office365itpros.com/2021/03/10/microsoft-updates-teams-powershell-module-2-0/

Comment: This answered all my questions, and downloading the update solved my problem.  Thank you very much!